# Is the Borel-Cantelli Lemma applicable here?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory

Consider $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of random variables taking values in the set $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ where $\mathbb{P}(X_{n} = i) > 0 $ for every $i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ which are independent and identically distributed.

I would like to know if the Borel-Cantelli lemma applies to the event given below:
\begin{align*}
(\forall v\in\mathbb{N}_{>0})(\exists u\in\mathbb{N}_{>0})((u\geq v)\wedge(X_{u} > u - v))
\end{align*}
which is very similar to the definition of $\limsup$, where the difference lies on the fact that the event $\{X_{u} > u - v\}$ depends on $v$.

If this is not the case, could anyone give any suggestion as how to proceed?

I would like to receive a hint instead of a full answer.

**EDIT**

The answer to the proposed question has been given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463116/a-variation-on-the-borel-cantelli-lemma-theme/463117#463117).

I would like to thanks Iosif Pinelis for the contribution.

Comment: Ignore the second part of my comment please, I misread the question. But what exactly are you asking? Do you want to know if this event has prob 1?

Comment: @ChristianRemling I want to prove such event has probability zero to occur.

Comment: But this cannot work without further assumptions on the $X_n$. For example, if $X_n$ are all the same rv and $P(X_n=1)=1/2$, then the event has prob $\ge 1/2$ (since $u=v$ works on that part of the probability space).

Comment: @ChristianRemling does it help to assume that $\mathbb{E}(X_{n}) < \infty$? By the way, the random variables are i.i.d.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I want to prove the $\limsup$ has zero probabilty, not the event $\{X_{u} > u - v\}$.

Comment: Instead of linking to Iosif's answer in an edit to the question, please hit the tick next to his answer indicating you accept that as providing the answer you sought. This will also make the software know the question has been answered.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: the link is to an answer of Iosif on a *different* question. So I guess the appropriate course of action is to close this question a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @SamHopkins well in this case it's not so clear. That question seems to have been asked to _replace_ this question, as this question had been deleted. Treating the undeletion of this question as being a "re-asking", then it could indeed be considered as a duplicate of Iosif's question, asked before the undeletion. Very much a corner case, though.

Answer (score 0):

For the event
$$E:=\bigcap_v B_v$$
with
$$B_v:=\bigcup_{u\ge v}\{X_u>u-v\}$$
we have $P(E)=1$ if $EX_1=\infty$.

Indeed,
$$P(B_v)=1-\prod_{u\ge v}P(X_u\le u-v)
=1-\prod_{k\ge0}P(X_1\le k) \\
=1-\prod_{k\ge0}(1-P(X_1>k))=1,$$
because $\sum_{k\ge0}P(X_1>k)=EX_1=\infty$ and hence $\prod_{k\ge0}(1-P(X_1>k))=0$. So, for each $v$ we have $P(B_v)=1$. Hence, $P(E)=1$.

Generally, $P(B_v)=:p$ does not depend on $v$, and $p<1$ iff $EX_1<\infty$.

Comment: Two comments [1](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463048/is-the-borel-cantelli-lemma-applicable-here#comment1202057_463048) [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463048/is-the-borel-cantelli-lemma-applicable-here#comment1202059_463048) suggest that the asker is interested in whether $(\forall n.EX_n < \infty) \implies P(E) = 0$.  (Although, of course, such assumptions should really be part of the question.)

Comment: @LSpice : I did notice that. However, (i) that assumption seemed optional even in the comment: "does it help to assume that [...]?" and (ii) In the post itself, the OP wrote: "I would like to receive a hint instead of a full answer." Do you think that, even if this answer is not full, it can qualify at least as a hint? :-)