# A variation on the Borel–Cantelli lemma theme

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, limits-and-convergence, limit-theorems

Let $X,X_0,X_1,\dots$ be nonnegative independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables. Let
\begin{equation*}
    E:=\bigcap_{n\ge0}B_n,
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    B_n:=\bigcup_{k\ge n}\{X_k>k-n\}. 
\end{equation*}

It was asked (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/463048/36721) and [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463048/is-the-borel-cantelli-lemma-applicable-here#comment1202057_463048)) if then necessarily $P(E)=0$.

It [was shown](https://mathoverflow.net/a/463050/36721) that actually $P(E)=1$ if $EX=\infty$. Soon after that, the question, and with it the answer, were deleted by the OP.

The question remained as to what happens otherwise, when $EX<\infty$.

To wrap up this matter, below it will also be shown that $P(E)=0$ if $EX<\infty$.

Thus, we have a nice zero–one dichotomy.

However, the [Kolmogorov zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law) does not seem to be directly applicable here: even though the event $B_n$ depends only on the tail $(X_n,X_{n+1},\dots)$ of the sequence $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$, the sequence $(B_0,B_1,\dots)$ of the events is not nonincreasing, so that it is unclear if the event $E$ is in the terminal $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(X_0,X_1,\dots)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$To begin, note that
\begin{equation*}
    P(B_n)=1-\prod_{k\ge n}P(X_k\le k-n)
    =p:=1-\prod_{j\ge0}(1-P(X>j)). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
Next,
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{j\ge0}P(X>j)=E\sum_{j\ge0}1(X>j)\in[EX,EX+1),
\end{equation*}
since $\sum_{j\ge0}1(X>j)\in[X,X+1)$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    p<1\iff EX<\infty. 
\end{equation*}

In particular, we have $P(B_n)=p=1$ for all $n$ if $EX=\infty$, and then clearly $P(E)=1$.

The case when $EX<\infty$, and hence $p<1$, is more interesting. To consider this case, take a natural $d$ and and let
\begin{equation*}
    C_i:=\bigcup_{(i+1)d>k\ge id}\{X_k>k-id\}\quad\text{and}\quad
    D_i:=B_{id}\setminus C_i
\end{equation*}
for $i=0,1,\dots$, so that the events $C_0,C_1,\dots$ are independent,
\begin{equation*}
    P(C_i)\le P(B_{id})=p,
\end{equation*}
and (cf. \eqref{1})
\begin{equation*}
    P(D_i)\le P\Big(\bigcup_{k\ge(i+1)d}\{X_k>k-id\}\Big)
    =1-\prod_{j\ge d}(1-P(X>j))=:\ep_d.
\end{equation*}
Then, for any natural $q$,
\begin{equation*}
    P(E)\le P\Big(\bigcap_{i=0}^{q-1}B_{id}\Big)
    =P\Big(\bigcap_{i=0}^{q-1}(C_i\cup D_i)\Big) \\ 
    \le P\Big(\bigcap_{i=0}^{q-1}C_i\Big)+\sum_{i=0}^{q-1}P(D_i)
    \le\prod_{i=0}^{q-1}P(C_i)+q\ep_d
    \le p^q+q\ep_d. 
\end{equation*}
Note now that $\ep_d\to0$ as $d\to\infty$, because the product $\prod_{j\ge 0}(1-P(X>j))$ converges (to $1-p>0$). So, letting $d\to\infty$ and then $q\to\infty$, we get $P(E)\le0$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: One of MO users once said that answering one's own questions is uncommon on MO, when the OP knows the answer right away. In fact, even before posting the question, the OP sees the prompt "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, [Q&A-style](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)". At that link, we find the following, in particular: "To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged*.** This seems quite reasonable to me, if the main purpose of MO is sharing math knowledge.

Comment: You could perhaps validate it (it is correct and it has been already validated by the community).

Comment: @AugustoSantos : I will provably do that later, when the system allows me to do that.